# Finger Print Authentification codenameone

Tags: codenameone, fingerprint

I'm trying to create an authentification using the [FingerprintScanner](https://github.com/codenameone/FingerprintScanner) library in codenameone.
But it lacks documentation , only one example is provided :

```
        scanFingerprint.addActionListener(e -> {
            Fingerprint.scanFingerprint(value -> {
                hi.add("Scan successfull!");
                hi.revalidate();
            }, (sender, err, errorCode, errorMessage) -> {
                hi.add("Scan Failed!");
                hi.revalidate();
            });
        });
```

how do i get the value of the fingerprint?
I have tried printing the value.toString(), it's empty and it's of type Object .

Answer (score 1):

There is no access to the fingerprint itself as that isn't available on iOS. In iOS the fingerprint will authenticate if this is one of the owners of the device which should in theory work for Face ID as well.

The assumption is that a user with access to the device is using it. On Android there is far more information available but we didn't expose it to keep the code portable.

Comment: Hello , isn't it possible to implement the same iOS feature on android ?( i'm talking about the future of the lib , since it's not that useful right now for android ) thank you for your quick answer

Comment: iOS doesn't expose fingerprint data. It's useful to verify that your user is the device owner. So if a user logged in and then says he's OK with using fingerprint you can use this lib to verify that he is one of the users authorized on the device. If you have more creative use cases they will probably only work on Android. You can look at the native interfaces of this lib which on Android are just Android code and enhance them to support additional features you might want.